# JDBC BigDecimal - Precision Issue

Tags: java, jdbc, bigdecimal, hp-nonstop, sqlmx

When reading a decimal value with 12 digits after decimal point from a table using `resultSet.getBigDecimal("COL1")` it returns the value with some additional numbers at the end. For instance, the value on the table is **29963.26**, but the value returned by rs.getBigDecimal and rs.getString is **29963.260000000002**

Another example, value on the table is **26.76** but the value returned by `rs.getBigDecimal('COL')` is **26.759999999998**

Any suggestions to get over it?

Comment: What is the actual datatype of the column you're retrieving? The behaviour (retrieved value) suggests it is actually a double precision. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes, the database we are using is HP NonStop SQL/MX and the datatype used is double precision. 

To simplify this how do I round the following values to 69.0235 and retain scale as 12, so the final value should be 69.023500000000,  

BigDecimal priceInBg = new BigDecimal("69.023499999999");
priceInBg.setScale(12, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)